# SQL Table Structure Dilemma (Creating a reference(?) table to assist in queries)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table structure dilemma.

I currently have three tables:

```
Store
+------+------+
| SID  | Desc |
+------+------+
Relative
+------+------+
| RID  | Desc |
+------+------+
Job
+------+------+
| JID  | Desc |
+------+------+
```

The `Store` table will be used to populate a Drop Down. It contains about a dozen rows representing various chain stores that may be located in one or multiple states. I need to be able to populate a drop down based on the state of the person in the application.

The `Relative` table will also be used to populate a drop down after a value is chosen in the `Store` drop down. It contains about a dozen rows representing relative types (e.g. 'son', 'daughter', 'mother' etc.). I need to be able to populate this drop down based on the `Store` chosen and the state of the person in the application. To give an example, say a `Store` allows employees to hire their own `mother` or `father` relatives, but in state X they only allows them to hire their `mother` (I know its an odd example, but it's just for understanding); in this case I want the box to populate with `mother` and `father` in all states but X, where it would populate with `mother` only.

Finally, the `Job` table will be used to populate a list of jobs (there are about 30 rows in the table). List list will depend on the Store and the State (because jobs my be state specific and/or store specific) and would populate after the `Store` or perhaps the `Relative` drop down was chosen.

I have the following table that could work to allow what I want to happen:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
| State | SID | RID | JID |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Where I would join to this table when populating the drop downs and the list, but it doesn't really seem optimal, and it could have quite a few rows. Is there another structuring of tables that anyone would feel is more appropriate? Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I think the example might be *too* odd to be useful :-(

Comment: Ugh.. sorry. I was mainly just trying to get across the idea that the `store` rows may or may not populate based on whether they have locations in a state, and the `relative` rows are filtered first by the chosen `store` then further by state requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table structure would work.. But this is how I would do it...

[image]